# Can I use one Trigger and one sequence (as auto_increment of pk) for several tables?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

And for what is option CACHE?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Race_SEQ
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 10;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RACE_INC
  BEFORE INSERT ON RACE
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    :NEW.RACE_ID := RACE_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
  END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same sequence to generate the primary key for many tables.  It generally doesn't make a lot of sense to do so, but you can.  It doesn't cost you anything to have many different sequences and it generally makes for a more sensible application design when `race_seq` is used to populate the `race` table and `foo_seq` is used to populate the `foo` table rather than having all the tables use the same sequence.

You would need one trigger per table.  A trigger can only be defined on a single table.

The `cache` attribute specifies how many values for the sequence should be cached (per node if you happen to be using RAC).  That makes generating new values more efficient at the expense of increasing the number of gaps that are created.  In general, you'd use larger caches for sequences the more frequently rows are inserted.